# É possível um input no meio de um print em Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, input

Algo como um `input` no meio de um `print`, é possível?

Estou tentando fazer algo assim:

```
print (f "Eu quero digitar {input ('')} palavras.")
```

Se eu precisar de algum módulo pygame ou o que for...

O que eu quero é uma resposta de tipo de entrada entre dois textos como:

```
QUERO DIGITAR |_ PALAVRAS
```

`|` significa o cursor do mouse indicando onde digitar e `_` significa o `input`.

Estou usando o Python 3.

---

Desde já agradeço a todos pela possível ajuda. Eu acho que as próximas versões do python deveriam implementar isso .. pq é uma boa eu perguntar ao usuário por ex n° de _______ casas

_______ seria onde o usuário Digitaria isso num input.               Seria uma espécie de print(f"eu tenho {input()} ideias")

Comment: Por favor, redija sua pergunta em português uma vez que estamos no [pt.so].

Answer (score 3):

Cara, pelo o que eu entendi é super simples.

Seria algo do tipo:

```py
input = raw_input()
print("I want to type " + input + " words.")
```

E se você quer que escrever a primeira parte do texto, parar a execução, ler o input e continuar o texto você pode usar:

```py
print("I want to type ", end="")
input = raw_input()
print(input + " words.", end="")
```

Mas essa última implementação só irá funcionar em Python 3. Como você mencionou no título que está usando Python 3, então sem problemas :)

Esse último parametro permite que você escolha qual será último caracter, que por padrão é `"\n"`, mas desse jeito que eu mostrei você define para uma string vazia, ou seja, nada.

Comment: a função raw_input não foi renomeada pra input() ? Aqui a raw_input não funciona... Tentei com input e não chegou ao meu resultado.
Por sinal dei uma pesquisada e ela realmente foi renomeada pra input() apenas, ou seja o raw_input não funciona mais, ele fica até irreconhecível no pycharm

Comment: I didn't get what I want yet, the raw_input() function doesn't work in python3.7

Comment: Desculpe por este erro. Fiz de cabeça, sem testar. Mas o importante é passar a idéia hehe ^^

Comment: Mas creio que o comentário do Pedro Heriqu está mais alinhado com o que você esteja procurando...

Answer (score 1):

- Acho que é isso aqui que você quer:

python

```
# Definimos o começo e o fim da frase:
começo_da_frase = "Eu quero digitar "
fim_da_frase = "____ palavras"
espaço = len(começo_da_frase)*" "

print(espaço,fim_da_frase,"\r",começo_da_frase,flush=True,end="")
input('') #explicação abaixo
```

- Explicação:
  Esse é uma das formas de resolver, não é muito elegante mas foi o que eu consegui pensar rápido aqui.

Então é o seguinte, você quer imprimir:

"Eu quero digitar |___ palavras" e receber uma entrada que será inserida no local marcado com "|".

- Logo você precisa voltar na linha.

Então você imprime um **espaço** para o começo da frase, imprime o **final_da_frase**, volta ao começo da linha "\r" e imprime o **começo_da_frase**. Agora você parou o cursor bem no começo do "___", **então é só você pedir o input**!

Mas atenção! Ao dar print, a função te joga no começo da linha seguinte, evite isso colocando a clausula **end = ""**

Defeitos da solução:

- Ao digitar mais caracteres do que len("____") o texto do usuário começa a apagar o **final_da_frase**

Observações:

- Talvez seja possível resolver o problema que citei com o pacote [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), ele gerencia o prompt te dando maior controle sobre essas coisas, mas é algo avançado demais pra mim haha
- O nome do "\r" é [Carriage Return](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), ou CR

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não chegou ao resultado que eu quero (mas sou grato pela ajuda/disposição) enfim, até imaginei que esse flush me ajudaria, eu queria que meu input não paralisasse o print seguinte...

Comment: Então, trabalhar só com a Standard Library vai te dar um pouco de dor de cabeça. o Curses deve resolver seu problema, mas eu não faço a menor ideia de como executar o código, embora isso parece algo bem básico eu não encontrei nenhuma forma elegante de resolver.

Comment: E você deveria pensar em migrar seu código pra algo com uma user interface mais moderna, Kivy é uma ótima library pra começar, principalmente pq te permite exportar pra mobile sem ter que programar infernos em Java.

Comment: Agradeço as dicas. Vou dar uma busca de qualquer forma. Peço que olhe o comentário final do tópico